# Cant access textviews in recycler view when scroll beyond what is initially visible

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, onclick

I am kind of a newbie here. I am trying the use a recyclerview to display items in an SQlite table. Wahat I need it to do is that when an item is clicked a context menu displays asking to take one of three actions. One of the items requires that I get the data from one of the textviews for the position selected. It works fine when I click an item that is initially viewable however if I scroll down to an item that was not initially viewable it crashes at the point where it tries to get access to the textview. Here is the error:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.RelativeLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

**Activity:**

```
package com.cascadia.nutrak;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import static com.cascadia.nutrak.FoodDbHelper.s1;


public class MyKitchen2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    DBRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

    RecyclerView myFoodDBRecView;

    String qty;
    FoodDbHelper myFoodDB;
    public String foodItemSelected;
    boolean isInserted;
    TextView idView;
    String dBaseID;

    String selPosition;




    public void gotoCupboard(View view) {

        //Create an "Intent" to go to ManageFoodActivity
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManageFoodActivity.class);

        //pass info to second activity

        //myIntent.putExtra("Friend Chosen", friendList.get(i));  //pass chosen friend as a string

        //Start the intent
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }

    public void goHome(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
    }


    public void goToMngTodaysFood(View view) {

        //Create an "Intent" to go to next activity SecondActivity
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManageTodaysFood2.class);

        //Start the intent
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }




    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_kitchen2);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);

        myFoodDB = new FoodDbHelper(this);
        mDatabase = myFoodDB.getWritableDatabase();

        myFoodDBRecView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myFoodDBRecView);

        myFoodDBRecView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        myFoodDBRecView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        //Use class DBRecyclerViewAdapter to create a new adapter and Run getAllItems function to get and put the masterFoodDB into the adapter "mAdapter".
        mAdapter = new DBRecyclerViewAdapter(this, getAllItems());

        //Assign the adapter and its contents (should be the whole MF database) to the recyclerView
        myFoodDBRecView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        itemClickSupport.addTo(myFoodDBRecView).setOnItemClickListener(

                new itemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View view) {

                    selPosition = String.valueOf(position) ;

                    registerForContextMenu(recyclerView); //This means that when touched it will popup a context menu setup below.
                    recyclerView.showContextMenuForChild(view);
                    unregisterForContextMenu(recyclerView); //This means that when touched it will popup a context menu setup below.

                    }
                }
        );

    }//End onCreate



    //Get the entire master food database and order by description
    private Cursor getAllItems() {
        return mDatabase.query(
                dBaseContract.masterFoodDB.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                dBaseContract.masterFoodDB.MF_COL_1 + " DESC"
        );
    }


        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, menu);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            Log.i("The item is", String.valueOf(item));


            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.iatethis:

                    Toast.makeText(this, "I ate this seleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //Here we ask for a quantity
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alert.setTitle(foodItemSelected);
                    alert.setMessage("Enter Quantity Consumed");

                    // Set an EditText view to get user input
                    final EditText qtyInput = new EditText(this);

                    //limit edit text to numbers only

                    qtyInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |
                            InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL |
                            InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);

                    //Set alert dialog view to use
                    alert.setView(qtyInput);

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            qty = qtyInput.getText().toString();
                            Log.d("", "Pin Value : " + qty);

                            //Get todays date
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            String date = sdf.format(new Date());

                            RecyclerView myFoodDBRecView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myFoodDBRecView);

                            //get the child record at the positionb
                            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) myFoodDBRecView.getChildAt(Integer.parseInt(selPosition));

                            //Get access to text view in recylcer view child
                            TextView idView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.idView);

                            dBaseID = idView.getText().toString();

                            Log.i("The position is", selPosition);
                            Log.i("The dBaseID is", dBaseID);

                            FoodDbHelper getRecordHelper = new FoodDbHelper(MyKitchen2.this);

                            //go get entire record for the selected dBaseID
                            getRecordHelper.returnAllSingleRecord2(dBaseID); //delete fooditemselected from above

                            //Debug code to make sure we have all the data from the record.
                            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                                Log.i("s1 " + i, " = " + s1[i]); //Verify we have all data in array
                            }
                            isInserted = myFoodDB.insertConsumedData( //run the insertConsumedData boolean method in FoodDBHelper on main database

                                    date, qty, s1[1], s1[2], s1[3], s1[4], s1[5], s1[6], s1[7], s1[8], s1[9], s1[10], s1[11] //Insert data returned in S1 into consumed table
                                    // leave out s1[0] as it is the key from mstr table
                                    //add date and qty and then data from master 1-10
                            );

                            if (isInserted = true) {

                                Toast.makeText(MyKitchen2.this, "Data inserted into todays food", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(MyKitchen2.this, "Data failed to insertinto todays food", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            return;
                        }
                    });


                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    return;
                                }
                            });
                    alert.show();

            return true; //always when item was handled

                case R.id.viewedit:

                    Toast.makeText(this, "view/edit selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true; //always when item was handled
                case R.id.delete:

                    Toast.makeText(this, "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    FoodDbHelper dbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(MyKitchen2.this);
                    // Log.i("Still Have it?", "?  " + selPosition);
                    dbHelper.remMasterSingleRecord(dBaseID); //delete fooditemselected from above

                    mAdapter = new DBRecyclerViewAdapter(this, getAllItems());
                    myFoodDBRecView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                    Toast.makeText(MyKitchen2.this, "Item removed from Cupboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    return true; //always when item was handled

                default: //This has to be at end
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);  //put return super inside default case


            }

        }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Special functions

    //This disables the back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {}

}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foodItemView"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descView"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/foodItemView"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView52"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foodItemView"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Cals" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calsView"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foodItemView"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView54"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foodItemView"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Carbs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carbsView"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foodItemView"
        android:layout_marginStart="135dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView56"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descView"
        android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Prot" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/protView"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descView"
        android:layout_marginStart="225dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView58"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descView"
        android:layout_marginStart="270dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Fat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fatView"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descView"
        android:layout_marginStart="315dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView60"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Recycler View**

```
package com.cascadia.nutrak;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class DBRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DBRecyclerViewAdapter.masterFoodViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;


    public DBRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;
    }


    public class masterFoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { //} implements View.OnClickListener {

        //Initialize all the text views
        public TextView idText;
        public TextView nameText;
        public TextView calsText;
        public TextView protText;
        public TextView carbsText;
        public TextView fatText;
        public TextView descText;


        //Here we fill the viewholder
        public masterFoodViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            //Here we assign the listLayout.xml TextView components to the TextView variables
            idText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idView);
            nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodItemView);
            calsText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.calsView);
            protText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.protView);
            carbsText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.carbsView);
            fatText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fatView);
            descText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descView);
        }
    }


        @Override
        public masterFoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            //Inflate the Recycler View using mContext and listLayout.xml
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, parent, false);


            return new masterFoodViewHolder(view);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(masterFoodViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            //Bind your datasource, in this case SQlite dbase, to the ViewHolder

            //Cursor through all records
            if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                return;
            }

            //Here we are loading the dbase column values into variables
            String id = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBaseContract.masterFoodDB.MF_ID));
            String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBaseContract.masterFoodDB.MF_COL_1));
            String cals = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBaseContract.masterFoodDB.MF_COL_2));
            String prot = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBaseContract.masterFoodDB.MF_COL_3));
            String carbs = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBaseContract.masterFoodDB.MF_COL_4));
            String fat = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBaseContract.masterFoodDB.MF_COL_5));
            String desc = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBaseContract.masterFoodDB.MF_COL_11));

            //Here we are loading the dbase columns, now in variables, into the listlayout textviews to display to user
            holder.idText.setText(id);
            holder.nameText.setText(name);
            holder.calsText.setText(cals);
            holder.protText.setText(prot);
            holder.carbsText.setText(carbs);
            holder.fatText.setText(fat);
            holder.descText.setText(desc);



        }//end onbindviewholder

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }





    //declare interface for recycler view on item click listener
    private  OnItemClicked onClick;

    //make interface like this
    public interface OnItemClicked {
        void onItemClick(final int position);
    }

    public void setOnClick(OnItemClicked onClick)
    {
        this.onClick=onClick;
    }


    }
    //end of activity
```

Comment: You should post which line is crashing.

Comment: Sure. It is crashing here: 

  TextView idView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.idView);

In the MyKitchen2 activity...

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerLists recycle views that aren't visible. So I wouldn't expect the textview to have the value you want. Instead you should try fetching the string from whatever array you're using to set data to the view with like

```
mAdapter.get(position)
```

Hard to say because I don't see what line of code you're talking about

I think you're talking about this

```
  //get the child record at the positionb
                        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) myFoodDBRecView.getChildAt(Integer.parseInt(selPosition));

                        //Get access to text view in recylcer view child
                        TextView idView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.idView);
```

If so try

```
dBaseID = myFoodDBRecView.adapter.get(selPosition);
```

You shouldn't try to retrieve the id from a textview that may or may not be loaded in. Instead save it to the adapter or a hashmap or something

Comment: TextView idView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.idView); In the MyKitchen2 activity...

Comment: @LKS is the value you need stored in some array? You should try getting it from there instead. It's unreliable to try and get data from a recycler view

Comment: I am getting the position. I can log it. The view is visible when I scroll to it. It works for items that are initially viewable. It seems the adapter is not updating on scroll???. Maybe an onScroll listener???.

Comment: @LKS I think the issue is RecyclerLists don't load all your data at once, and you're trying to fetch a view which doesn't exist anymore because it has been deleted by the list. It only loads data that is visible, which is why you can't depend on saving references to views and fetching data from them. You need to save it to an array or something

Comment: The value is in a textview inside the listlayout.xml for the recyclerview. It is the SQlite database ID for the record I want to act upon.

Comment: Once I scroll to it, doesn't it become visible?.

Comment: I like your array idea though. I think I can make that work..